# I created this procedure in SQL but it will not execute, What Have I done wrong?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Code:

```
Create Procedure sp_EmpBonus (@BonusAmt int)
AS
    Select 
        FirstName, LastName, Title, 
        Salary, 
        Salary * Cast('xxx' as int) TotalBonus
    From 
        Employee    
    Where 
        Cast('xxx'as int) = @BonusAmt

EXEC sp_EmpBonus '.10'
```

Error:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Procedure sp_EmpBonus, Line 0
>   Error converting data type varchar to int.

Comment: You are trying to convert `xxx` into an `INT`.  This is why you're getting the error.  As for how to fix it, you need to tell us what you're trying to do, because otherwise all we can say is "don't try to convert text to an `INT`".

Comment: I am trying to show the bonus amount for the percent entered as a parameter

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: I have to use it for my class...

Answer (score 0):

You declared an integer parameter, but `'.10'` (one-tenth) is not an integer and can't be cast to it from a `VARCHAR`.

Comment: `.10` is a perfectly valid cast to an `INT`.  `Select cast(0.10 as int)` -> `0`.  But there are additional problems in the proc - the fact that he's calling it with a `VARCHAR` value rather than numeric, and that he is doing a convert on a `VARCHAR` literal to an `INT`.

Comment: @Siyual: `.10` is, `'.10'` is not. `SELECT  CAST('.10' AS INT)` throws the same error

Comment: Yes, but your answer refers to it as one-tenth `.10`, not `'.10'`

Comment: Create Procedure sp_EmpBonus2 (@BonusAmt int)
AS
Select FirstName, 
  LastName,
  Title, 
  Salary, 
  Salary * CAST(.10 as int) TotalBonus
From Employee 
Where CAST(.10 as int) = @BonusAmt

EXEC sp_EmpBonus2 .10*** the only problem now is the bonus cloumn is all zeros, thanks for the help I was given

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

`EXEC sp_EmpBonus  10`

When you write some thing in`'somevalue'` (single quotes) that means its not an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Several things here:

- As mentioned in other posts you are calling your sp with string versus an int.
- Next your CAST function looks incorrect (see sample below).
- Finally, you are calling the procedure with a float value, yet it seems you want to process everything considered as int.

Sample:

```
Create Procedure sp_EmpBonus (@BonusAmt int)
AS
Select FirstName, 
    LastName,
    Title, 
    Salary, 
    Salary * CAST(TotalBonus as int)
From Employee   
Where CAST(TotalBonus as int) = @BonusAmt

sp_EmpBonus 10
```

Comment: Carlos, in your example where you typed TotalBonus, I have .10 and it works....almost all the columns are correct except the Total Bonus one which is all 0.00 for a Total.. which ovbiously is not what I want it to be

Comment: Scopes, it is because you are casting the float to an int.  If you cast 0.10 to an int the value will be 0.  Thus in your last column where you have Salary * 0 which will give you 0 for all the rows.  Since you are dealing with monetary values you should consider using float data type or some variation thereof and being mindful of rounding.

Comment: Scopes, I read your comment above where the 0.10 is supposed to be a percent value.  Perhaps if you tell us exactly what your are trying to do we can help more.  I am gathering that you want to find where bonus amounts are a certain percentage of individuals salaries?